# General table into a quartely table

Tags: r

Using R:

Initially, the table looks like : PS (Date column is in the format : (dd/mm/yyyy))

```
      Date        Q           Season    
01/01/2017     1023           Winter
01/02/2017     2233           Winter
01/03/2017     1312           Winter
01/04/2017     1194           Spring
01/05/2017     907            Spring
01/06/2017     1939           Spring
01/07/2017     3264           Summer
01/08/2017     2232           Summer
01/09/2017     3574           Summer
01/10/2017     1533           Fall
01/11/2017     907            Fall
01/12/2017     1778           Fall
```

Similarly, for  2018 and 2019  (can change for different products so the table below needs to be dynamic in terms of the number of rows)

I want the table to be like:

```
Date         Winter                   Spring                 Summer                      Fall

2017  Sum of Q (01/17-03/17)   Sum of Q (04/17-06/17)  Sum of Q (07/17-09/17)    Sum of Q (10/17-12/17)
2018  Sum of Q (01/18-03/18)   Sum of Q (04/18-06/18)  Sum of Q (07/18-09/18)    Sum of Q (10/18-12/18)
2019  Sum of Q (01/19-03/19)   Sum of Q (04/19-06/19)  Sum of Q (07/19-09/19)    Sum of Q (10/19-12/19)
```

I/P Data:

structure(list(Time = structure(1:30, .Label = c("2017-02-01",
"2017-03-01", "2017-04-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-06-01", "2017-07-01",
"2017-08-01", "2017-09-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-11-01", "2017-12-01",
"2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-05-01",
"2018-06-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-08-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-10-01",
"2018-11-01", "2018-12-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01",
"2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01"), class = "factor"),
Qty = c(1638.2520529, 0, 0, 1644.9257156, 1629.2808217, 2227.0057667,
586.0942485, 593.1155226, 1664.6943283, 2193.6993566, 2696.5906737,
3354.9333327, 2749.2299918, 3835.7584686, 2791.6314399, 2145.3504203,
3311.5319066, 4446.0188521, 2740.9135081, 2786.6458353, 3839.8798065,
3216.524473, 566.3303976, 0, 0, 0, 0, 559.2043639, 0, 528.4764685
), Quarters = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3",
"Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2",
"Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2",
"Q2", "Q2", "Q3"), Season = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Winter",
"Spring", "Summer", "Fall"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,
-30L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Date` to date class, extract year from it and cast data into wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Time = as.Date(Time),
         year = format(Time, '%Y')) %>%
  select(-Time, -Quarters) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Season, values_from = Qty, values_fn = sum)
  #OR in old tidyr
  #tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Season, values_from = Qty, 
  #                   values_fn = list(Qty = sum))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  year  Winter Spring Summer  Fall
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2017   4335.  1645.  4442. 4452.
#2 2018   6670.  8773. 10498. 9843.
#3 2019      0    559.   528.   NA
```

---

An alternative, instead of using `values_fn` we can `sum` it first and then cast to wide.

```
df %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Time = as.Date(Time),
         year = format(Time, '%Y')) %>%
  select(-Time, -Quarters) %>%
  group_by(year, Season) %>%
  summarise(Qty = sum(Qty)) %>%
  tidyr::spread(Season, Qty)
  #OR
  #tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Season, values_from = Qty)
```

Comment: Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Comment: @InVinci Does it work for the data I have shared in my answer? If yes and you have trouble applying it to your data please share your data using `dput` in the same way as I have shared. If your data is large you can do `dput(head(df, 20))` and update your post.

Comment: Shared. I changed the column names as per my data using your snippet but it threw the above error.

Comment: @InVinci Try updated answer. It works for me for the data you have shared.

Comment: same error again - Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Comment: Which data are you using? Are you trying with the data shared in your post?

Comment: I have put the entire df now. Kindly check, Ronak.

Comment: Are you sure that is entire `df`? It has only 6 rows and only 1 year of data i.e 2017 and this still works for me.

Comment: Kindly, check now.

Comment: This new data still works for me without any errors. :(. Can you restart R and try this again in a fresh R session?

Comment: I tried post restarting and doing it in a new session. The same error again. :(

Comment: I am not sure what might be wrong. Can you try the updated answer. I added `type.convert` to change factors to characters.

Comment: hmmm...it runs for me without any error. I updated the post with another alternative, check if that helps.

Comment: Works well.. The new snippet.. I just don't know what the previous error was for?

Comment: @InVinci I think I found it why it doesn't work for you. You have old `tidyr` version. If you use `tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Season, values_from = Qty, values_fn = list(Qty = sum))` in the last line it should work.